# Adding images to a list in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make a game where mines spawn randomly around the screen and you have to avoid them. I want to have a list of mines and spawn all of them around the screen. But whenever I try to add an image to a list I get an error message: `'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'append'`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show us your code so we can see the bug. Also the full trace of the error to further debug.

Comment: use the code `image = pygame.image.load("Image.png")` to load an image and then use `list.append(image)` to add the image to the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to append the pygame image object to your list,
not the other way around:

```
img_lst.append(img)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use this code:

```
import random # imports random so you can generate random numbers
import pygame # imports pygame

pygame.init() # initiates pygame
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,800)) # creates a pygame window

image = pygame.image.load("mine.png") # loads an image called mine.png, you can change this if you want.

mine_x = [] # makes a list called mine_x
mine_y = [] # makes a list called mine_y
# this part appends random coordinates to the lists.
for x in range(num):
    mine_x.append(random.randint(min_x,max_x))
    mine_y.append(random.randint(min_y,max_y))

# main loop
while 1:
    # for loop loops through the whole list of coordinates
    for i in range(len(mine_x)):
        # show the image (mine.png) at the coordinates
        screen.blit(image, (mine_x[i],mine_y[i]))
```

Comment: RandomHuman it didn't draw the images, and there was no error.

Comment: You need to add a background. Try to add `screen.fill(0,0,0)` to the while loop and you should see images on a black background. Make sure the for loop is behind the background.

Comment: RandomHuman in: for i in range(num):   What does that number represent is it the amount of mines in the list, is it the height and width of the screen?

Comment: RandomHuman nvm I found out what it represents. But what does the num in for x in range represent

Comment: In: for i in range(num)  I can only put 1 or else I get the error list index out of range

Comment: both nums should be the number of mines.

Comment: RandomHuman In regards to the code that you showed in your first response, I am young and am still pretty new to pygame and programming in general so if you could please explain the code that you showed me in a more beginner friendly way. Like why we need this part of the code and what it does please. Thanks!.